# How to mute mic while Recording using UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, video-recording

I am using UIImagePickerController for recording video in one of my application. i have successfully Recorded video. But now i want to mute mic (video without audio) while recording video.
i have searched Alot but not a single clue about it.
please help me about this issue.
is it possible or not. if possible than how.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your app to be in app store , then there is no apple approved method to actually mute whole iPhone.There are certain libraries but they are not approved.

[Apple's documentation on Audio Session](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Basics/Basics.html)

According to the documentation you can only ask the user to have the phone silenced physically and you can respond to certain audio changes such as other sounds,phone calls, email sounds but you cannot mute programmatically.

Also See this [Documentation on Programming in iPhone](http://www8.cs.umu.se/education/examina/Rapporter/BenjaminEriksson%28kand%29.pdf) See the part 3.3 for Audio.(Events that can be accessed and performed in iOS).

Comment: THANKS @roronoa. please share a link so that i can tell my client that this task of "mute mic" is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AVFoundation framework to record a video without the sound, check at this :

[AVFoundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188)

Comment: Can you please share some code snippet for video recording without sound. thanks in advance