# Turn off mic in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, openears

I am using `openEars` to detect speech. It takes one second of silence to detect the end of command.

What I want is to disable the microphone for 1 second.
Can anyone tell me that how to disable mic for 1 second?

Answer (score 0):

As already said in [How to mute mic while Recording using UIImagePickerController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795162/how-to-mute-mic-while-recording-using-uiimagepickercontroller) :

> If you want your app to be in app store , then there is no apple
> approved method to actually mute whole iPhone.There are certain
> libraries but they are not approved.
>
> [Apple's documentation on Audio Session](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Basics/Basics.html)
>
> According to the documentation you can only ask the user to have the
> phone silenced physically and you can respond to certain audio changes
> such as other sounds,phone calls, email sounds but you cannot mute
> programmatically.
>
> Also See this [Documentation on Programming in iPhone](http://www8.cs.umu.se/education/examina/Rapporter/BenjaminEriksson%28kand%29.pdf) See the part 3.3
> for Audio.(Events that can be accessed and performed in iOS).

Regards,